# How do I get a Tumblr Poster's avatar and username?

Tags: tumblr

I am completely new to making themes in Tumblr and had a question.

So I'm coding my blog and I want to make it so that for each post, the post displays the poster's avatar and username. For example, when I post to this blog I want my post to show my avatar and username. If I were to reblog someone else's post, I would want that poster's avatar and username. Also, if someone likes or reblogs MY posts, I would want to be able to see their username and avatar as part of the Tumblr notes. Basically, I need a way to find anyone's avatar and username and then display it through CSS. I've tried looking around, however I haven't been able to find any answers for my problem.

Comment: I think I can assist you with what you want to achieve, but I'm still unsure — so to clarify, are you trying to do something similar, e.g., like on https://joliebean.tumblr.com/? So when you reblog someone's post, it shows the poster's avatar, and when you post your own, it shows your own avatar, correct? I can share a bit of the code if you'd like!

Comment: As for your last question, I'm still a bit unsure about that too — by default, Tumblr notes should display the avatar of someone liking or reblogging your post. Would you mind sharing your theme progress so that I can take a look?